# Xunit to return a new argument

Tags: c#, xunit

I am new to Xunit. I throw a new exception in my code :

```
throw new NotImplementedException("Missing UPC. File is corrupt");
```

in my test file I wrote:

```
[Fact]
public void ParserRow_Throws_Exception_For_Null_UPC()
{
    var record = GetRessoRecord();
    record.UPC = "";

    RevenueReportItem result = Sut.ParseRow(record);

    Assert.Throws<NotImplementedException>(() => Sut.ParseRow(record));
}
```

The error message in the Test Explorer says

> System.NotImplementedException : Missing UPC. File is corrupt

How do I add in the returned quote?

Comment: you're calling the tested method twice. remove the first call that's outside of the assert, as it will throw the exception and halt test execution.

Comment: thanks @CeeMcSharpface. wish you had answered that in a separate answer, so i can show it solved the issue!

Answer (score 1):

1. The synchronous variant of `Throws<>` is now obsolete.
2. You're calling the tested method twice. Remove the first call that's outside of the assert, as it will throw the exception and halt test execution.
3. The call to `Throws<>` returns the exception object, from which you can retrieve and check the message, like so:

```
[Fact]
public async Task ParserRow_Throws_Exception_For_Null_UPC() 
{
    var exceptionDetails = await Assert.ThrowsAsync<NotImplementedException>(() => {
        throw new NotImplementedException("foo");
    });

    Assert.Equal("foo", exceptionDetails.Message);
}
```

Comment: when the unit test runs, it hits the place where the exception is thrown and the code stops. any way around that?

Comment: I think your statement is missing one important part. Throws is considered as obsolete for async code (Func<Task<T>>), not for sync code!!!

Comment: blank solution, new xunit project with latest .net core and latest xunit package, starting from a non-async fact, asserts compile as expected just only Throws<> would not compile with the info that it is obsolete. it even is a compiler error, not a warning. I found this very odd as well when I realized it while answering.

Comment: @CeeMcSharpface: I can't reproduce this. See https://gist.github.com/jskeet/5bf5776c84ed2becae1c931626871992, which compiles with no problem for both xUnit 2.4.1 and 2.4.2-pre12.